# Change font properties of math expression in axis label pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I thought it was simple just to change the font of the axis label by using:

```
ylabel={$\frac{Su}{\sigma_{pc}^{'}}$ x},
ylabel style={font=\Huge},
```

However it does NOT work, I really don't understand why. Here is an example code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}              % To generate the plot from csv


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[dots/.style={circle,draw=blue,fill=blue, inner sep=-1pt}]

    \begin{axis}[
    % SIZE
    scale only axis, % scale axis to specified size, otherwise 
    width=6cm,
    height=6cm,%{},
    % AXIS
    grid,
    grid style={solid,gray!50},
    % TICKS
    xticklabel pos=right,
    % LABELS
    xlabel={$\gamma_{zr} [\%]$},
    x label style={above,font=\tiny},
    xlabel near ticks,
    ylabel={$\frac{Su}{\sigma_{pc}^{'}}$ x},
    ylabel style={font=\tiny},
    ylabel near ticks,
    % LEGEND
    legend style={at={(0.01,0.01)},anchor=south west,font=\scriptsize},
        legend columns=1,
        legend style={/tikz/column 3/.style={column sep=10pt}},
        legend cell align=left,
    ]


\addplot [solid, black, mark=none, mark options={orange,scale=1}]{x^2};                         


    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlabel near ticks` and `ylabel near ticks` override the changes you have made with `xlabel style`/`ylabel style`. Swap the order, and it works fine.

`xlabel near ticks` does `/pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel}`, while `xlabel style` does `every axis x label/.append style={...}`. Hence, when you have `xlabel style` first, you append something to the existing definition of `every axis x label`, but that is then completely redefined by `xlabel near ticks`, so you loose your customization.

(As a sidenote,`tikz` loads `pgf`, but `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, so explicitly loading all three is not really necessary.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}              % To generate the plot from csv


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[dots/.style={circle,draw=blue,fill=blue, inner sep=-1pt}]

    \begin{axis}[
    % SIZE
    scale only axis, % scale axis to specified size, otherwise 
    width=6cm,
    height=6cm,%{},
    % AXIS
    grid,
    grid style={solid,gray!50},
    % TICKS
    xticklabel pos=right,
    % LABELS
    xlabel={$\gamma_{zr} [\%]$},
    xlabel near ticks,
    x label style={above,font=\tiny},
    ylabel={$\frac{Su}{\sigma_{pc}^{'}}$ x},
    ylabel near ticks,
    ylabel style={font=\Huge},
    % LEGEND
    legend style={at={(0.01,0.01)},anchor=south west,font=\scriptsize},
        legend columns=1,
        legend style={/tikz/column 3/.style={column sep=10pt}},
        legend cell align=left,
    ]


\addplot [solid, black, mark=none, mark options={orange,scale=1}]{x^2};                         


    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```